# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\COP3718\insert caller_info.php on line 18

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to insert info into a table using Notepad ++ and when opening on the local root I am receiving the error message I am very new to this and am running into errors left and right that I can not figure out. Here is the code I am inputting:

```
<?php


$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$franchise = $_POST['franchise'];

include("inc_connect_local.php");

mysql_select_db ("testproject");

$query=("INSERT INTO caller_info (first_name, last_name, franchise, 
VALUES ('$Tammie', '$Thomas', '$Minneapolis');

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

echo 'Database updated';

?>
```

Comment: You're missing a double quote at the end of the `$query` string.

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated, and you are highly vulnerable to sql injection! `$query=("INSERT INTO caller_info (first_name, last_name, franchise, 
VALUES ('$Tammie', '$Thomas', '$Minneapolis');`

Comment: @Pranavc probably in his inc_connect_local.php file, although he should be putting an obfuscated copy of that as well...

Comment: In addition to what others have said - you're assigning `$Tammie` etc to the database, but never actually defining what those variables are.

Comment: Use a text editor with syntax highlighting. Also, you should use the search before asking a question (this question has been answered before).

Answer (score 3):

Your query  should looked like this

```
$query="INSERT INTO caller_info (first_name, last_name, franchise) 
VALUES ('$Tammie', '$Thomas', '$Minneapolis')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `PDO` and `PDOStatement` for security reasons.
`mysql_*` functions are officially **deprecated**.

```
try {

    if (!isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['franchise'])) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Invalid parameters');
    }

    $pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:dbname=testproject;host=localhost;charset=utf8',
        'root',
        '',
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
        )
    );

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO caller_info(firstname, last_name, ffanchise) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute(array($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'], $_POST['franchise']));

    echo 'Database updated';

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```